# Reset the changed values doesn't work in other Ctrl (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, reset

I'm a bit confused about my problem. In fact I've 2 views and ctrl who are working with a service.
First View contains a tablelist with the items which will load from a WebAPI. The service makes requests to the server and provides to order. Also I'm using another service to transfer the selected item row in the other Ctrl.
Here's the Code:

View1:

```
//view1.html
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in namelist" ng-click="open(this.item)">
      <td>{{ item.fname }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.lname }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Ctrl1:

```
//FirstCtrl
$scope.namelist = reqService.names.query();

$scope.open = function (item) {
  $scope.selectedItem = item;           
  modalService.openDialog($scope.namelist, $scope.selectedItem);
}
```

HTTP-Service:

```
//Service for HTTP Requests
testApp.factory('reqService', ['$resource', 'baseUrl', function ($resource, baseUrl) {
    return {
        names: $resource(baseUrl + '/api/name/:Id', {
            Id: '@Id'
        }, {
            'update': {
                method: 'PUT'
            }
        })
    }
}]);
```

Service for modal dialog:

```
//Modal dialog service
testApp.factory('modalService', ['$modal', function ($modal) {
    return {
        openDialog: function (namelist, selectedItem) {
            return $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'views/view2.html',
                controller: 'SecondCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    namedList: function () {
                        return namelist;
                    },
                    selected: function () {
                        return selectedItem;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Ctrl2:

```
testApp.controller('SecondCtrl', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'namedList', 'selected', 'reqService', '$http'..., function (...){
   /*copy of the original items*/
   $scope.copyItem = angular.copy(selected);

   $scope.cancel = function () {
      $scope.selected = angular.copy($scope.copyItem);
      $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
   }

   $scope.reset = function () {
      $scope.selected = angular.copy($scope.copyItem);
      selected = angular.copy($scope.copyItem); //doesn't work
   }
}
```

My question is how can I reset the tablelist? When I click on resetBtn, it resets only the form in my modal window but the changes remain in the table list?! I cannot reset the resolve variable "selected".

Comment: Interesting problem, you could go for another shared factory that contains the most current state of the tablelist and inject that one in both your controllers.

Comment: @Mikey When I even leave the variable `$scope.selected` in `cancel()` the changes in the list remain, although I have defined the `dismiss('cancel')`.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a case pass by value|reference.
Read this [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language) .

It would be interesting to see how it works if you try to pass a function that reset the value instead.

### One possible implementation

Ctrl1:

```
$scope.open = function (item) {
    $scope.selectedItem = item;           
    modalService.openDialog($scope.namelist, function(e){
        if (e === undefined) {
            return $scope.selectedItem;
        } else {
            $scope.selectedItem = e;
        }
    });
}
```

Ctrl2 began :

```
testApp.controller('SecondCtrl', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'namedList', 'selected', 'reqService', '$http'..., function (...){
    /*copy of the original items*/
   $scope.copyItem = angular.copy(selected());

   $scope.cancel = function () {
      $scope.selected = angular.copy($scope.copyItem);
      $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
   }

   $scope.reset = function () {
      $scope.selected = angular.copy($scope.copyItem);
      selected(angular.copy($scope.copyItem));
   }
}
```

Ok I know it's dirty but it's just to test the assumption.

Comment: Thx for your answer, but it doesn't work correctly. But I think I have a solution. I need only an answer for this question. How can I post a selected object back to an array of objects? For example can I do this `reqService.post({data: selectedItem})` ?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding your question, it is a bit unclear, but I think if you want to post an object to an array of objects you would have to do this: reqService.post([{data: selectedItem}])